# Get the indexes of javascript array elements that satisfy condition

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this:

```
[{prop1:"abc",prop2:"qwe"},{prop1:"abc",prop2:"yutu"},{prop1:"xyz",prop2:"qwrq"}]
```

I'd like to get the index of all elements that satisfy a condition; in this case, when `prop1 == "abc"`.  So the desired output is something like `[0,1]`.

Struggling to find a clean way of doing this?
`indexes = a.findIndex(x => x.prop1==="abc")` will return `0` for the above array, because it stops at the first successful find.

I feel like I want something like this: `indexes = a.filtered(x.index() => x.prop1==="abc")`

Comment: Is `reduce`, `filter` and `map`, or `for` loop best practice?

Wow lots of answers in short order..  was this a dumb question?

Comment: p.s. please don't use `==` when you should be using `===`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method.

```js
var data = [{prop1:"abc",prop2:"qwe"},{prop1:"abc",prop2:"yutu"},{prop1:"xyz",prop2:"qwrq"}];

console.log(
  data.reduce(function(arr, e, i) {
    if (e.prop1 == 'abc') arr.push(i);
    return arr;
  }, [])
)

// with ES6 arrow syntax
console.log(
  data.reduce((arr, e, i) => ((e.prop1 == 'abc') && arr.push(i), arr), [])
)
```

---

With simple `for` loop

```js
var data = [{prop1:"abc",prop2:"qwe"},{prop1:"abc",prop2:"yutu"},{prop1:"xyz",prop2:"qwrq"}];

var res = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (data[i].prop1 == 'abc') res.push(i);
}

console.log(res)
```

---

Or use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Filter) with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map) method(Not an efficient way since it needs to iterate twice).

```js
var data = [{prop1:"abc",prop2:"qwe"},{prop1:"abc",prop2:"yutu"},{prop1:"xyz",prop2:"qwrq"}];


console.log(
  data.map(function(e, i) {
    return i;
  }).filter(function(e) {
    return data[e].prop1 == 'abc';
  })
)

// With ES6 arrow syntax
console.log(
  data.map((_, i) => i).filter(e => data[e].prop1 == 'abc')
)
```

Comment: Your example with `filter` does not work in general.

Comment: You can write it in ES5/ES6/whatever, using `filter` and then a `map` *does not work*. In this specific case it yields the correct result, but only because the condition matches the first x items in the array. If that condition is not given, it will not work.

Comment: @str :  thanks, updated the answer :) ... we just need to revert the order with a slight variation

Comment: actually, two iterations doesn't make it less efficient if yo'ure splitting the same number of operations across the two iterations. filter/map is much more readable and generally more performant that custom reduce functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` function.

```js
var array = [{ prop1: "abc", prop2: "qwe" }, 
             { prop1: "abc", prop2: "yutu" }, 
             { prop1: "xyz", prop2: "qwrq" }];

var indexes = array.reduce((a, c, i/*Current index*/) => {
  if (c.prop1 == "abc") a.push(i); //Add the found index.
  return a;
}, []/*Accumulator to store the found indexes.*/);

console.log(indexes);
```

## Resource

- [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array.prototype.reduce` with `shorthand if` to make it with a single line of code:

```js
var arr = [ {prop1:"abc",prop2:"qwe"}, {prop1:"abc",prop2:"yutu"},{prop1:"xyz",prop2:"qwrq"} ];

var indexes = arr.reduce((m, e, i) => (e.prop1 === 'abc' && m.push(i), m), []);
console.log(indexes);
```

Comment: Can you explain what is this comma and m for ? 

```(e.prop1 === 'abc' && m.push(i), m)```

Comment: @berkan It's JavaScript's [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). It ensures that `e.prop1 === 'abc' && m.push(i)` is always executed, and that `m` is always returned as the result. Can be rewritten as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48584347/1273042).

Answer (score 1):

There is a purely functional way of doing this, but it's not particularly efficient because it requires three separate linear scans through the array:

```
let indexes = array.map((e, i) => [i, e])
                   .filter(([i, e]) => predicate(e))
                   .map(([i, _]) => i);
```

where

```
let predicate = e => e.prop1 === 'abc';
```

This works by creating a temporary array where each element is itself and array containing the original index and the element.   It then filters out those where the predicate function is not true, and then strips back the arrays so that they only contain the indices.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me:

```js
var data = [{prop1:"abc",prop2:"qwe"},{prop1:"abc",prop2:"yutu"},{prop1:"xyz",prop2:"qwrq"}]
var indexes = []

data.forEach((element, index)=>{
 if(element.prop1 =="abc"){
   indexes.push(index)
 }
});
    
console.log(indexes)
```